# trying to set the value of a field but it is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image] 
this is my frontend

I'm getting the value of variables `interestRate` and `monthlyPayment` from an API. I just want to set these values in the frontend. Here is my code:

```
class Display extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    this.calculateAPR();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      this.calculateAPR();

    }

  calculateAPR = () => {
    let x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('amount'));
     a=x[0].amount; 
     t=x[0].years;


    fetch("https://herokuapp.com/interest?amount="+a+"&numMonths="+t)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(

        (result) => {
          //console.log(result);
          interestRate = result.interestRate;
          monthlyPayment = result.monthlyPayment.amount;
          console.log(interestRate, monthlyPayment);
        },
      )

        this.calculateMonthlyRepayment(monthlyPayment);
        this.percentageAPR(interestRate);
  };

  calculateMonthlyRepayment = (z) => {
    return <p>${z}</p>;
  };

  percentageAPR = (z) => {
    return <p>{z * 100}%</p>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex">
        <DisplayChild func={this.percentageAPR()} text="interest rate" />
        <DisplayChild
          func={this.calculateMonthlyRepayment()}
          text=" monthly repayment"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is where I'm displaying these values, but the values are not showing up:

```
const DisplayChild = ({ func, text }) => {
  return (
    <span>
      {func} <small>{text}</small>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the values in *state information*. As it is, you're just passing them to functions that immediately return elements that are then thrown away. (You're also not handling errors from `fetch` correctly. You're not the only one, the `fetch` API has a design flaw encouraging this footgun, I've written it up [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)

More about handling state [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

See comments:

```
class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) { // *** Constructor with initial state
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        interestRate: 0,  // *** Use appropriate initial values, 0 probably isn't the right choice
        monthlyPayment: 0
      });
  }

  // *** SOMETHING needs to call this function. You might do it from componentDidMount, for instance.
  calculateAPR = () => {
    let x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('amount'));
    a=x[0].amount; 
    t=x[0].years;

    fetch("https://ftl-frontend-test.herokuapp.com/interest?amount="+a+"&numMonths="+t)
      .then(res => {                                   //
        if (!res.ok) {                                 // *** Note the necessary error handling
          throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status); //
        }                                              //
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            interestRate: result.interestRate,
            monthlyPayment: result.monthlyPayment.amount
          });
        },
      )
      .catch(err => {
        // *** Handle/display error here
      });
  };

  // *** You can have these as functions if you want, but since they're pure functions
  // it A) Isn't necessary to re-create them for every instance like this, and B) Is
  // entirely possible for them to be `static` (or even outside the component and closed
  // over).
  calculateMonthlyRepayment = (z) => {
    return <p>${z}</p>;
  };

  percentageAPR = (z) => {
    return <p>{z * 100}%</p>;
  };

  render() {
    // *** You may want logic here to render differently when you don't have the data yet
    return (
      <div className="flex">
        <DisplayChild func={this.percentageAPR()} text="interest rate" />
        <DisplayChild
          func={this.calculateMonthlyRepayment()}
          text=" monthly repayment"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but i have state in my app component(the parent component)

Comment: @ABHINEETSINGH - If you have the ajax call in the component above, the component above **has** to have state, because it will be rendered before that ajax call has completed. So it has at least two states: 1. ajax is still outstanding, 2. ajax is complete. If you don't want it to have state, put the ajax call in the parent component and only render this one when you have the data.

Comment: thanks man, it really helped. i added state in the parent component itself and now it works perfectly fine